# How to filter journalctl logs for Errors for ASPNET core application hosted on Linux

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, kestrel, systemd-journald

I have a website built using ASP.NET core 2.0.7 and it is hosted on Ubuntu 16.04. I have done like this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x

I use systemd to make it start automatically, and logs are sent to journald.

I can get my logs with commands like

```
journalctl --no-pager -u lic6.service > lic6.log
```

However, if I only want to have the errors and above, I should be able to use -p, i.e.

```
journalctl --no-pager -u lic6.service -p 3 > lic6.log
```

according to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs

However, it seems that Microsofts log format is not compatible with the -p filtering of journalctl. What should I change?

Comment: I also asked at https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/2679#issuecomment-399168371

Answer (score 2):

Tmds.Systemd.Logging is a systemd logger for ASP.NET Core (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging). It logs priorities and also does structured logging. You can find more info at: https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.Systemd.